# Java Counting from user input

Tags: java

New Java student and I am writing an assignment for school (week 1), I have made the program work for the most part, but i want it to count up to the user input when they input a valid number.(ex I love the 1 ways, I love thee 2 ways, etc up to the input number). Everything works except when i start adding for statements.Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your name? ");
        name = scanIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);

        System.out.println("How much love do you need? (Enter a number from 0-10)");
        int love = scanIn.nextInt();
        String message;
        int line;
        if (love < 1) {
            message = "Everybody needs some love! " + name;
        } else if (love > 9) {
            message = "You can't handle that much love " + name;
        } else {
            for (love = 1; love <= line; love++) {
                message = "I love thee " + love + " ways";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(message);
        scanIn.close();
    }
```

Comment: You need braces for multiline statements.

Comment: @AndrewL. What multi-line statement did you envision would be fixed using braces in that code? I mean, sure code structure sucks with those bad indentations, and sure it would be good to have braces around the `for` loop, but as the code currently is, braces are not *needed*, since there are no multi-statement blocks of code.

Comment: @Andreas at this point the code doesn't need them but for the desired output the user needs to add some braces.

Comment: Randy, you only have one `println()` statement, printing the value of `message`, so how do you expect multiple lines to be printed? The `for` loop will iterate as needed, and when it ends, `message` will have the *last* value, and that is what will be printed. If you want multiple lines printed, then you need a `println()` *inside* the `for` loop, but then the other lines assigning to `message` won't print anything, so fix your indentations to better see the program structure, then sit back and reconsider what you want.

Comment: Andreas, thank you forgiving me something to make me think about what and where i was missing it. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be a few issues with the code, as @Andrew L. Said there was an

1. An issue with multi line braces
2. You hadnt initialized the variables line or message
3. Since line hadnt been initalized the third else being reached would only perform once if at all as line is null and love would be the number you input.

After some formatting i think this was roughly what you were trying to achieve:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        try (Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("What is your name? ");
            name = scanIn.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);

            System.out.println("How much love do you need? (Enter a number from 0-10)");
            int love = scanIn.nextInt();
            String message = null;
            //int line=1;
            if (love < 1) {
                message = "Everybody needs some love! " + name;
            } else if (love > 9) {
                message = "You can't handle that much love " + name;
            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i <= love; i++) {
                    message = "I love thee " + love + " ways";
                }
            }
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you wanted to loop through and print multiple lines instead of printing it once at the end, note you would still need to either move the other print lines into the other if/else if conditions or keep the original outside to print after also:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= love; i++) {
                    message = "I love thee " + love + " ways";
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
```

But the for-loop still seems somewhat unnecessary, since you already know the value of love so you should just be able to join the value to a string in a regular way without a loop. Anyway hope this helps in someway and good luck with your programming!

Answer (score 0):

This might Help:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Counting {

public static void main(String[] args) {String name;
Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What is your name? ");
name = scanIn.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello " + name);

System.out.println("How much love do you need? (Enter a number from 0-10)");
int love = scanIn.nextInt();
 String message=null;

 if (love<1){
  message = "Everybody needs some love! " +name;
 }
   else if (love>9){
  message = "You can't handle that much love " +name;
   }
   else{
        for (int line=0;line<=love;line++)   
  message = "I love thee " + love + " ways";
   }
  System.out.println(message);
  scanIn.close();
  }
  }
```

It was a bit difficult to understand your question.